# Object orientated analysis and design - Class Diagrams

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have a school project to do and it involves developing a prototype app that runs locally on my PC, checking for changes to files etc in a specified file directory and upon picking up any changes I need it to copy any changed files into "the cloud" (a kinda stripped down dropbox if you like)

I've did some research and set up an amazon web services account/amazon s3 and im thinking of trying to sync my files up to that.

The app doesn't have to be in a specific language so I also looked at some options with regards to that and came across python which looked usable but I am totally new to it and was wondering how hard it would be to write this sort of thing with python and I would really appreciate any advice on how I could go about this or any pointers?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: I think you will benefit from investigating the source code of rsync. This is the kind of tool you are asked to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would be accomplished by a combination of Tim Golden's [Watch a Directory for Changes](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) and [Amazon's Boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/index.html).

Gluing the two together is left as an exercise to the student.

Comment: This advice is excellent. HOWEVER, liammcdee, before you jump into working with these specific packages, make sure you understand basic Python programming, or you will get very confused. Online tutorials and resources abound.

Comment: Thanks NobRuked this is brill, I have been reading loads of stuff online on how to achieve this but most of what I came across was over complicated for what I needed :) yeah I have ran through a few python tutorials but thanks for the heads up David